# Cross Thread Error Treenode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, treeview

I'm really struggling with Cross Threading and could do with a pointer or 2!

The below is run from a menu option from a right click menu on a treeview and basically extracts certain files from a directory `(GetCISFiles)` copies them to a new folder then zips them up. The respective node should then be cleared from the treeview. I keep getting the `Cross Thread Operation not Valid` error. I've debugged through and the error appears right before the final Message Box appears. As in the code i've tried a delegate sub for clearing the node (which is where i think the problem is) however its still an issue.

```
Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To UBound(AllDetails)
        Dim startpath As String = tempMail & tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath

        Dim fileout As String = outMail & AllDetails(x).uCode & "-" & AllDetails(x).uOps & "-" & Date.Parse(AllDetails(x).pDate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        lstPlanned.BeginUpdate()

        Try
            Call GetCISFiles(startpath)

            Dim zip As String = inMail & AllDetails(x).uFile & ".zip"
            Dim txt As String = inMail & AllDetails(x).uFile & ".txt"
            Dim pdf As String = inMail & AllDetails(x).uFile & ".pdf"
            Dim fldr As String = inMail & AllDetails(x).uFile & "\"

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(fileout & "\", fileout & ".zip", CompressionLevel.Optimal, False)
            Directory.Delete(fileout & "\", True)
            File.Delete(zip)
            File.Delete(txt)
            File.Delete(pdf)
            Directory.Delete(fldr, True)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(tempMail & tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)

            Dim del As ClearNode
            del = New ClearNode(AddressOf ClearNodea)
            del.Invoke()

            Dim sRoot As String = tempMail

            Dim sPath As String = tempMail

            DeleteEmptyFolders(sPath, sRoot)

            MsgBox("Job sent to CIS")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
    lstPlanned.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Delegate Sub

```
Public Delegate Sub ClearNode()
Private Sub ClearNodea()
    tvProgress.SelectedNode.Remove()
End Sub
```

Looks like it comes back to the following code

```
 watchfolder = New System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()

    watchfolder.Path = My.Settings.Out

    watchfolder.Filter = "*.zip"

    AddHandler watchfolder.Created, AddressOf CompleteArray
    AddHandler watchfolder.Deleted, AddressOf CompleteArray


    watchfolder.EnableRaisingEvents = True
```

Where would i begin to look at invoking here?

Comment: You should read up on Invoke and BeginInvoke.  If you're getting this cross-thread error, it means that you're not using these correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The UI elements cannot be accessed from a background thread.  To make this work you need to use `Invoke` to execute the `Remove` method on the UI thread.

```
Private Sub ClearNodea()
  Dim act As Action = Sub() tvProgress.SelectedNode.Remove()
  tvProgress.Invoke(act)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, actually found that its relating to a File System Watcher I have running to update a listbox. I've updated the original post with the code I'm using for that

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of .Net, you can do:

```
Private Delegate Sub ClearNodeDelegate()
Private Sub ClearNode()
    If tvProgress.InvokeRequired Then
        tvProgress.Invoke(New ClearNodeDelegate(AddressOf ClearNode))
    Else
        tvProgress.SelectedNode.Remove()
    End If
End Sub
```